# Get the latest date based on another column

Tags: sql, sas

[image]

I have a dataset that includes a column DATETIME and a column BANKCASENUMBER. I want to select the rows with the latest dates for each BANKCASENUMBER.

This is what I've tried:

```
PROC SQL;    
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNT AS 
   ORDER BY t1.DATETIME LIMIT 1
   SELECT t1.LOGINNAME, 
      t1.FORENAME, 
      t1.SURNAME, 
      t1.BANKCASENUMBER, 
      MAX(t1.DATETIME), 
      t1.'Inbound/outbound'n, 
      t1.'succesvol?'n
  FROM WORK.WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNTACTIVITIES t1
  GROUP BY t1.BANKCASENUMBER;
QUIT;
```

The returned table should givall the rows with the latset DATETIME for each BANKCASENUMBER. So each BANKCASENUMBER should appear once.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using...

Comment: If you hover your cursor over the `SQL` tag you will see that it asks you to specify which version of SQL you're using.  MySQL would do this differently from SQL Server, for example.  Also, when you try something that doesn't work, please describe what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.  In your case, you would have received an error message, which should *always* be included in your questions.

Comment: I eddited the tags, I'm using sql in SAS enterprice guide

Comment: I included an image of the data

Comment: @Parfait - If you take notice of details, you'll see that SAS was tagged ***after*** our comments, as was the mention of `proc sql`.

Comment: Please don't post an image of the data.  It's much more helpful if you post the actual data, not a picture of it

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for. The idea is to get the latest timestamp for each bank case number in a subquery, and join it to your main table.

```
PROC SQL;    
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNT AS
    SELECT t1.LOGINNAME, 
      t1.FORENAME, 
      t1.SURNAME, 
      t1.BANKCASENUMBER, 
      t1.DATETIME, 
      t1.'Inbound/outbound'n, 
      t1.'succesvol?'n
    FROM WORK.WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNTACTIVITIES t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT  t2.bankCaseNumber,
                MAX(t2.dateTime) as maxDateTime
        FROM WORK.WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNTACTIVITIES t2
        GROUP BY t2.BANKCASENUMBER
    ) m
        ON  m.bankCaseNumber = t1.bankCaseNumber
        AND t1.dateTime = m.maxDateTime
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: I looked at the results of this code, and it's not what I was looking for. This just gives me all the DATETIMES for each BANKCASENUMBER grouped. I want to extract only the latest DATETIME for each BANKCASENUMBER.

Comment: @AtalAtmar - I think you're mistaken.  The sub-query finds the most recent `DateTime` for each `BankCaseNumber`, and the outer query finds the full matching record for those `BankCseNumber, DateTime` combinations.

Answer (score 0):

this seems a little simpler.  Since we are grouping by LOGINNAME the having statement will refer to the max(DATETIME) within each group

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table QUERY_FOR_WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNT as
     select * from WORK_QUERY_FOR_ACCOUNTACTIVITIES
       group by LOGINNAME
       having DATETIME = max(DATETIME);
quit;
```